# How can I access custom properties in WebSphere?

Tags: websphere, sip

I have set some custom properties for a container in WebSphere, but I can't figure out how to read those properties back.  I've tried System.getProperty(...), but it's empty.

I've seen references to JMX, but wondered if there was a definitive answer.

Comment: Are you referring exclusively to SIP container custom properties?

Answer (score 0):

"Custom property" is a generate term in WAS configuration for applying arbitrary properties to all kinds of objects.  Custom properties on the JVM configuration object do translate to system properties that can be acquired using System.getProperty.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm attempting to configure a custom application router in the WebSphere SIP container.  It supports custom properties, but I can't find anything on how to access those properties.

Comment: Unfortunately, I know nothing about SIP, so any other information I could provide would just be guessing.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

SIP Servlets 1.1 Spec Section 15.4.2  defines the Application Router Packaging and Deployment.

javax.servlet.sip.ar.spi.SipApplicationRouterProvider system property can be used to override loading behavior and force a specific provider implementation to be used.

Alternatively you can try with Mobicents SIP Servlets if it doesn't work with IBM